# SpriteKit - Stop Objects Piling-Up

Tags: ios, macos, sprite-kit

I'm wondering what code I should add to stop rocks from piling up at the bottom of the screen and have them removed when resting (not moving).

Here is the code that creates the rocks. If you need any other code please let me know :)

```
-(void)addRock {

    SKSpriteNode *rock = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"asteroid"];
    rock.position = CGPointMake ([self makeRandomXWBetween:0 and:self.size.width], self.size.height);
    rock.name = @"rock";
    rock.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rock.size];
    rock.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    rock.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = rockCategory;
    rock.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = dodgerCategory;
    [self addChild:rock]; 
}

-(void)makeRocks {

    SKAction *makeRocks = [SKAction sequence: @[
                                                [SKAction performSelector:@selector(addRock) onTarget:self],
                                                [SKAction waitForDuration:0.3 withRange:0.0]
                                                ]];
    [self runAction: [SKAction repeatActionForever:makeRocks]];
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Best Regards,
Louis.

Comment: Please provide some context, specifically post the code that creates those objects and what the requirement is to remove them (after specific time? when hitting bottom? when resting?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the rocks to be removed when they are resting, they can be removed when their `velocity` property is zero.

You can check so in the `-update` method.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"rock" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){

        if ((node.physicsBody.velocity.dx == 0) && (node.physicsBody.velocity.dy == 0) && (node.position.y < self.size.height)) {
            [node removeFromParent];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: if (node.physicsBody.velocity.dx == 0 && node.physicsBody.velocity.dy == 0) should be if ((node.physicsBody.velocity.dx == 0) && (node.physicsBody.velocity.dy == 0))

Comment: Ok, for clarity's sake, I am updating the answer.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working when I add that code... any other code I need to add? @akashg

Comment: This code will remove the rock nodes only when they come to a complete rest. It won't work if the nodes keep moving about. Are there any other conditions for which you want to remove the nodes?

Comment: @akashg Sorry, I should have stated that I get a heap of syntax errors when I add that code.

Comment: Probably because of the missing } brace... Have corrected that in the answer. Any other error?

Comment: @akashg Hmm... I don't get any more errors but the rocks aren't falling now.

Comment: That's because they initially have a velocity of zero when they are added. I have added another condition, please check the edited answer.

Comment: @akashg I know I'm not supposed to post many "thanks" comments, but this really helped me big time. Thank you so much!